# PHP Checking if the date is today or up to 7 days in future

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am trying to solve a supposedly basic problem. I want to check that if the user has entered valid date. Valid date in our application is that of today or up to next 7 days. So any date within that range is valid. Any date in past or from 7th day upward from now will be considered as invalid.

I have written a small function to solve this:

```
function is_valid($d)
{
if( strtotime($d) < strtotime('+7 days') ) {
return true;
}
else return false;
}
Usage : is_valid('01-20-2015');  //M-D-Y
```

But this is always returning true.

What am I doing wrong?

Ahmar

Comment: `strtotime()` is possibly unable to parse a format like `01-20-2015` unambiguously.  It's likely returning `(bool)false`

Comment: how to fix it @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Have you tried using the format Y-M-D?

Comment: You have answers that have been given below; consult them and let them if it worked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggeested in the comments - you don't consider `strtotime()` being unable to parse the date entered (invalid date format etc).

Try this code:

```
function is_valid($d)
{
   if( strtotime($d) !== FALSE && strtotime($d) < strtotime('+7 days') ) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
Usage : is_valid('01-20-2015');  //M-D-Y
```

You should also have in mind, that `strtotime` depends on server's timezone, as [described in docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Answer (score 1):

Its much easier to use the **DateTime** functions.

```
$yourDate = new \DateTime('01-20-2015');

// Set 00:00:00 if you want the aktual date remove the setTime line
$beginOfDay = new \DateTime();
$beginOfDay->setTime(0,0,0);

// Calculate future date
$futureDate = clone $beginOfDay;
$futureDate->modify('+7 days');

if($yourDate > $beginOfDay && $yourDate < $futureDate) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` can not parse that date format. You need to be using YYYY-MM-DD

Use this test code for confirmation;

```
<?php
function is_valid($d) {
   if (strtotime($d) < strtotime('+7 day')) {
      return true;
   }
   else 
      return false;
}

var_dump(is_valid('2015-12-25'));

// Wrong format;
echo "Right: " . strtotime('2015-12-25') . "\n";

// Right format;
echo "Wrong: " . strtotime('01-20-2015') . "\n";
```

Can be seen here;
http://codepad.org/iudWZKnz